# Why can you edit answers and comments on deleted answers?

Tags: support, edits, deleted-answers

How come you can edit an answer or comments on an deleted answer?

Should everything not be locked to prevent changes in the deleted state (except for the OP of the answer or mods)?

Is this a bug?

Comment: If it is not mod deleted we can undelete, in which case it is beneficial if we first fix a post before it is undeleted. No need to have it locked.

Comment: @rene Even if it is mod deleted, it can still be fixed and flagged for undeletion.  Happens every now and then.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

While rare, posts can be improved to address the issue requiring deletion, and be undeleted.

There's no real need to prevent editing, the revision history means nothing is lost by allowing editing.

Any abusive edits of a deleted post can be addressed in exactly the same way as abusive edits of non-deleted posts.